# How to localize urls with routing in ASP.NET WebForms application - not MVC

Tags: asp.net, localization, routes

I have a webforms application (VB.net, .NET 4.0) which is translated in three languages and I managed to localize everything except the URLs. My preference is to use routing, so I'd like to find a solution in this direction (not URL rewriting or IIS rewrites, etc.)

Out of many read articles I stumbled into this one as well: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx, but this example is for MVC application. (As are the most of the questions here as well)

Any comments and ideas are very much welcome!

Comment: Why would you localize URLs at all? Is this a SEO thing?

Comment: yes, SEO is the main reason. Also, if you send links (or save bookmarks), it leads you to the translated content directly (without extra url parameters, which makes the whole thing cleaner).

Comment: You know the whole URL rewriting madness has gone too far when you see this question.

Answer (score 0):

I could implement Maarten's solution in a WebForms ASP.NET application as described below.

1. I downloaded his sample and opened with Visual Studio. As you see it the essential part of translated routing can be found in Routing folder.
2. I created a new Class Library project in my web application, and copied these 5 files. This project missed some assembly references, so I added `System.Web` and `System.Web.Routing` to it.
3. After this there was only one problem in `TranslatedRouteCollectionExtensions` class. The two extension methods used `MvcRouteHandler`. This is the only piece of code which depends on MVC. To eliminate this dependency modify both extension methods like this:

   ```
   public static TranslatedRoute MapTranslatedRoute(
           this RouteCollection routes, 
           string name, 
           string url, 
           object defaults, 
           object routeValueTranslationProviders, 
           IRouteHandler routeHandler, 
           bool setDetectedCulture)
   {
       TranslatedRoute route = new TranslatedRoute(
                                        url,
                                        new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
                                        new RouteValueDictionary(routeValueTranslationProviders),
                                        setDetectedCulture,
                                        routeHandler);
       routes.Add(name, route);
       return route;
   }
   ```
4. I added a reference in my Web Application to this Class Library project.
5. With this modification Maarten's example of register a translated route changes as follows:

   ```
   routes.MapTranslatedRoute(
           "TranslatedRoute",
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
           new { controller = translationProvider, action = translationProvider },
           new GeneralRouteHandler(),
           true
       );
   ```
6. Implementing a custom route handler is not a complicated process. You can find many [good](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) [articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx) about it.